# Rename a text file name

Tags: linux, command-line, rename, command

I have several text file and extract a few of the file name as shown below

```
DFC_2_31A_K14_G008_F2_001D.txt
DFC_2_31A_K66_G005_F1_001D.txt
DFC_2_31A_K66_G005_F2_001D.txt
DFC_2_33_I_K15_G001_F1_001D.txt
DFC_2_33_I_K15_G001_F2_001D.txt
YFC_6_80I_S27_G008_F1_001D.txt
YFC_6_80I_S27_G008_F2_001D.txt
YFC_6_80I_S79_G005_F1_001D.txt
YFC_6_80I_S79_G005_F2_001D.txt
GPC_10_161_A_B_K37_G001_F1_001D.txt
GPC_10_161_A_B_K37_G001_F2_001D.txt
GPC_10_161_A_B_K37_G002_F1_001D.txt
GPC_10_161_A_B_K37_G002_F2_001D.txt
GPC_10_161_A_B_K37_G003_F1_001D.txt
```

How could I make all the file names to have the same pattern as shown below (I want to have 6 under score in the file name    `\*\_\*\_\*\_\*\_\*\_\*\_001D.txt` )

```
DFC_2_31A_K14_G008_F2_001D.txt
DFC_2_31A_K66_G005_F1_001D.txt
DFC_2_31A_K66_G005_F2_001D.txt
DFC_2_33I_K15_G001_F1_001D.txt
DFC_2_33I_K15_G001_F2_001D.txt
YFC_6_80I_S27_G008_F1_001D.txt
YFC_6_80I_S27_G008_F2_001D.txt
YFC_6_80I_S79_G005_F1_001D.txt
YFC_6_80I_S79_G005_F2_001D.txt
GPC_10_161AB_K37_G001_F1_001D.txt
GPC_10_161AB_K37_G001_F2_001D.txt
GPC_10_161AB_K37_G002_F1_001D.txt
GPC_10_161AB_K37_G002_F2_001D.txt
GPC_10_161AB_K37_G003_F1_001D.txt
```

Comment: How, precisely, do the desired new names differ from the current names?  What have you tried? How did it not work as expected?

Comment: If they have A_B rename it to AB?

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in *_001D.txt; do 
    if [[ "$file" =~ "A_B" ]]; then 
        mv "$file" "${file//_A_B/AB}"
    fi
    if [[ "$file" =~ "_I_K" ]]; then 
        mv "$file" D"${file/_I_/I_}"
    fi
done
```

Iterating on all your files in a simple `for` loop, we first check to see if the filename has the pattern you want to modify.  If it is present, we then simply use `mv` and parameter substitution to derive the new filename.  The way this works is:

For a variable `haystack`, the syntax `${haystack/needle/pin}` will find the first instance of `needle`, and replace it with `pin`.  Using two `/`s (e. g. `${haystack//needle/pin}`) will replace *all* such instances rather than just the first.

Comment: The `161` has to be attached to it as well. See the last few filenames. But I'm kinda assuming these can be arbitrary strings of letters and numbers.

Comment: I have aslo a file name like DFC_2_33_I_K15_G001_F1_001D.txt and wanted to make FC_2_33I_K15_G001_F1_001D.txt

Comment: That is a more radical change, but if you have multiple files that match that pattern for a similar change, you can add another `if` statement to the `for` loop to handle those cases.

Comment: I have three kinds of file name, 1. separated by 6 under score 2. separated by 7 under score 3. separated by 8 under score. as shown in the above example I wanted to have all file names to have separated by 6 under score.   1.DFC_2_31A_K66_G005_F2_001D.txt
2.DFC_2_33_I_K15_G001_F1_001D.txt 3. GPC_10_161AB_K37_G001_F1_001D.txt

Comment: I have added another of the conversion cases.  You should now have the tools you need to handle any further such conversions yourself.

Comment: Like the saying says, "Give a freezing person a match and they'll be warm for three seconds.  Set a freezing person on fire and they'll be warm for the rest of their life."

Comment: That is assuming you can get them alight in the first place. Sometimes they just wanted a torch.